# OBIEE Scheduling reports

Tags: smtp, scheduling, obiee

I am having a problem trying to schedule a report in `OBIEE`. After some research I found that, if we want to do scheduling in OBIEE we have to install `SMTP` server on our system. Is that true?

I just installed the Hmail server on my system, and gave it the necessary information about port number, domain name, sender and receiver mail Id's. However, when I am running my report I get the following error.

```
Global Error: [nQSError: 77030] Oracle BI Presentation Server Connection Error: Unable to resolve the address for miracle_PC.
Error Codes: AXSBMN8D:
The operation completed successfully.
```

Here `miracle_pc` is my system name.

How can I resolve this problem to deliver a  report through email in OBIEE.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send email from OBIEE, then yes you need access to an SMTP server. This might be one within your company, from your internet service provider, from your webmail provider -- or you can host your own.

Looking at the error you've posted it looks like `miracle_PC` isn't a valid DNS entry so OBIEE can't find the SMTP server you've given it.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of OBIEE are you using? The configuration for 10.x.x.x and 11.x.x.x varies slightly, however take a look at the below url for ibot configuration in 11g.

https://praveenobd.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/setting-up-ibots-in-obiee-11g-2/

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you seem wanted to use OBIEE report schedule. 
In my experience, there is two different type of schedule.

1. Sending scheduled reports via email
2. Seeding scheduled reports (it is more likely run the report regarding 
         your schedule and save cache on the memory)

You can use both of them if you want.

Regarding this error, I would like to recommend that you need to test your email server first. The testing email server is not related to OBIEE. 
    The reason behind I am recommending to test your SMTP email server is that 
    it looks like OBIEE is not able to find DNS of your server or the 
    configuration might be invalid if the SMTP email server was working.

I understand that it does not look like a solution, but I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but for people still searching for a solution.

I faced the same problem and solve it by editing `/etc/hosts` file.

The hosts file contains lines of text consisting of an IP address in the first text field followed by one or more host names
if you want to read more you can go to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) link.

in your case it should be  `<Your_IP> <host_name> <miracle_PC>`